# Postgres: How to 'INSERT INTO ... IF NOT EXISTS ...'

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I've got a postgres table keeping track of schedule time slots for a couple of different schools and I'm trying to write a function (in javascript using the node-postgres library) that inserts 1 new row per time slot per day per school for the upcoming week.

Can anyone help me figure out the WITH command to be able to (in one query) check if a particular school/date/time combination already exists in the table and, if not, insert it? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add a constraint to your database.

```
ALTER TABLE school_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT school_date_time_uniq 
UNIQUE (school_name, school_date, school_time);
```

Is there any particular reason you want to be using a with clause?

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot. There wasn't any particular reason I wanted to use a WITH clause, just mistakenly thought that was how I needed to do it.

Comment: Great, welcome to SO. If you try an answer and it works select that answer so other users can see the issue has been resolved.  Thanks and good luck!